# Kinect 2 SDK: MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint?

Tags: kinect-sdk

What is the Kinect 2 equivalent of MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint?

In the 1.8 and below SDK, it was used to map skeleton points to the color or depth images like this:

```
DepthImagePoint newJointPos = coordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skeletonPt, depthFormat);
```

But that method is missing from the new Kinect 2 CoordinateMapper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapCameraPointToDepthSpace() is the Kinect2 equivalent of Kinect1's MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint().

Given a `skeletonPt` of type `CameraSpacePoint`:

```
DepthSpacePoint depthPt = _mapper.MapCameraPointToDepthSpace(skeletonPt);
ColorSpacePoint colorPt = _mapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(skeletonPt);
```